# How to view the browser session launched by selenium in Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, session, vnc, vnc-viewer

Started the selenium server remotely on Linux server and tried to execute a test case on it. So this opened a firefox browser in some session and started executing the test case.
When I tried to view the browser by using VNC viewer i could not find anything there as VNC uses a new session.

So my question is how can i view/access the currently running browser which is in some session ?

Can someone please help me in this ?

Comment: So no way to do this ?

Comment: Hi Sunil, Where you able to get this done?
I am in a similar situation but I am closer to reaching the target. My issue is VNC is showing a black screen instead of the browser.

I found a better blog post which has listed down all steps and it's really good. 
http://antonina.burlachenko.com/2013/09/sharing-of-remote-screen-for-selenium.html#comment-form

Let me know the current status of your problem.